# Google Sheets how to extract nth decimal number using INT() or TRUNC()?

Tags: google-sheets

I attempted to extract the first decimal number from a dataset through a very simplistic use of INT(), and was dumbfounded to discover that both INT() and TRUNC() can return 0 out of a calculated 1 :

[image]

First of all, would it be possible to explain this behaviour ? Did I miss something ?

Then, what would be a good way to actually extract the nth decimal number from each number of my dataset while avoiding this pitfall ?

Comment: I confirmed the behavior you described but can't yet explain it. 
I provided an approach to get your digit. The problem doesn't occur if there are digits in the 2nd position to the right of the decimal!? Interesting.

Comment: @Blindspots Thanks for the detailed answer with explanations and edge/type cases ! Encapsulated it into value() to get back integers, seems to work like a charm. Relieved that you could replicate my problem and found yourself equally surprised ; and obviously still extremely curious as to why this happens...

Comment: FYI I updated [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173430) to use VALUE for MOD's dividend instead of `*1` because it would fail specifically for currency as pointed out by [doubleunary](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/173423/google-sheets-how-to-extract-nth-decimal-number-using-int-or-trunc/173430?noredirect=1#comment164533_173430). My testing methodology was flawed as I tested currency using accounting which looks similar but behaves differently.  The current approach should be `=MID(MOD(VALUE(A1), 1), 3, 1)*1`

Comment: The second link therein is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Formula

Returns digit in specified position of the non-integer portion of a number.

```
=MID(MOD(VALUE(A1), 1), 3, 1)   //  returns number-as-text

=MID(MOD(VALUE(A1),1), 3, 1)*1  //  returns number
```

## Explanation

1. MID's **string** argument is a MOD function, so,

   ```
   =MID(string, starting_at, extract_length)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   =MID(MOD(dividend, divisor),
      starting_at, extract_length)
   ```

   - MOD returns the non-integer portion (remainder) of a **dividend**, and a **divisor** which in the case of `6.1` and `1` is `0.1`
   - The **dividend** is placed inside a VALUE function so that regardless of its number format, MID returns results based on the underlying number.
2. MID's **starting_at** is set to `3`, the character to the right of the decimal in `0.1`
3. MID's **extract_length** is set to `1` character

   ```
   =MID(MOD(VALUE(A1), 1), 3, 1)
   =MID(MOD(6.1, 1), 3, 1)
   =MID(0.1, 3, 1)
   =1
   ```

###### Notes:

- If `A1` is text, a **#VALUE!** error will be returned, the formula can be wrapped in IFERROR to handle it if this is a concern.
- If `A1` is an empty cell, or there is no digit in the position specified, an empty value will be returned.
- Result is a string. Sheets will coerce it back to an integer if used in a calculation.  For example,

  ```
  =ISNUMBER("5")=FALSE
  # but,
  =ISNUMBER("5"*1)=TRUE
  ```
- this can done preemptively by multiplying the formula by one or placing it inside the VALUE function. For example,

  ```
  =MID(MOD(VALUE(A1), 1), 3, 1)*1
  # or
  =VALUE(MID(MOD(VALUE(A1), 1), 3, 1))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first digit after decimal mark, use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=regexextract(to_text(A1), "\.(\d)")
```

To get the second digit, use `"\.\d(\d)"`, to get the third, use `"\.\d\d(\d)"`, and so on.

See [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), [regexextract()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098244) and [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

> dumbfounded to discover that both INT() and TRUNC() can return 0 out of a calculated 1

You are asking why a spreadsheet would consider the values 6.1 and 6.11 differently in this context:

`int(10 * (6.1 - int(6.1))) === 0`

`int(10 * (6.11 - int(6.11))) === 1`

This behavior is caused by the rounding rules mandated by the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. See [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/13045193)

Comment: Thanks for the link!